# SSIS Create text file with Header Row for every Detail Row

Tags: ssis

I need to generate a text file that has a header row for every detail row, like below.

Head|123

Detail|qwe|123|234A|aaa

Head|123

Detail|qwe|123|234B|aaa

How do I do this in SSIS?

Comment: You don't. SSIS does not support complex output like that

Comment: It could be done with a script task.   : )

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this in SSIS. Instead, you can return the output in required format from your source Query\stored procedure itself in a single column if you have any unique_id to distinguish the each detail row.

Example -

```
--Source table for Detail Rows -
CREATE TABLE SourceTable
    (
      id int primary key,
      col1 varchar(50),
      Col2 varchar(50)
    )
GO

--Sample Source Procedure to get data -
    Create Procedure dbo.SourceProc
as 
BEGIN

    SELECT
        Id,
        RecordType,
        DetailsRow
    FROM
    (    
        SELECT 
            id,
            2 as RecordType,
            CONVERT
            (
               VARCHAR(200),
                  'Detail|' + convert(varchar(5),id) +'|'
                  +col1+'|' + col2
            )as DetailsRow
        FROM
            SourceTable

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            Id,
            1 as RecordType,
            CONVERT(varchar(200), 'Head|123') as DetailRow
        FROM
            SourceTable
    )as A
    Order by Id, RecordType
END
```

- You can add this procedure as source to your OLEDB source and you can only use DetailsRow as output column from the source.
- Then, you can create the flat file connection manager with only one column of length 200 (this is for above example query) in the file and use it in the flat file destination.

Comment: I like this solution, however, my source DB is an Oracle DB, then I am calling a Stored Proc on a MSSQL to look up the value and add it to the output from Oracle.  I may investigate using a merge/union.